# kill -s SIGUSR1 is killing background process

Tags: bash, signals

I was testing around with Bash signals. I hadn't needed them before, so this is new to me.

```
#!/bin/bash
service_test ()
{
    trap 'echo received SIGUSR1;' SIGUSR1
    while true; do echo -n $'\e7\e[1;50H\e[0K'$(date  +%H:%M:%S:%N)$'\e8'; sleep 1; done
}

service_test &
echo $'USE "kill '"$!"$'"\t\tto kill the service\nUSE "kill -s SIGUSR1 '"$!"$'"\tto send SIGUSR1 to the service'
```

When I start this test script, I can send SIGUSR1 signals to the background service; the
background service isn't quitting.

However, when adding a `kill -s` command to the end of the script, I thought this would send the first SIGUSR1 signal to the background process automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash
service_test ()
{
    trap 'echo received SIGUSR1;' SIGUSR1
    while true; do echo -n $'\e7\e[1;50H\e[0K'$(date  +%H:%M:%S:%N)$'\e8'; sleep 1; done
}

service_test &
echo $'USE "kill '"$!"$'"\t\tto kill the service\nUSE "kill -s SIGUSR1 '"$!"$'"\tto send SIGUSR1 to the service'
kill -s SIGUSR1 $!
```

but that never starts the background process, so I thought `kill -s SIGUSR1 $!` is also always killing a process.

Then I recognized that there is a difference, if you wait till the background process is started, and then send `kill -s SIGUSR1 $!`, the background process receives the signal:

```
#!/bin/bash
service_test ()
{
    trap 'echo received SIGUSR1;' SIGUSR1
    while true; do echo -n $'\e7\e[1;50H\e[0K'$(date  +%H:%M:%S:%N)$'\e8'; sleep 1; done
}

service_test &
echo $'USE "kill '"$!"$'"\t\tto kill the service\nUSE "kill -s SIGUSR1 '"$!"$'"\tto send SIGUSR1 to the service'
sleep 1
kill -s SIGUSR1 $!
```

So why does Bash never start the service with `service_test & kill -s SIGUSR1 $!`?

I think at the time when `kill -s SIGUSR1 $!` is called, the trap inside the function isn't already defined - and SIGUSR1 is terminating the process. I have to wait till the trap is defined, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a simple race condition seems like the most straightforward answer; the background process has not yet executed the trap when it receives the signal.

For a quick and dirty fix, probably a much shorter sleep is sufficient; try `sleep 0.1`?

A proper solution would use a mutual exclusion mechanism, but these are OS-dependent and slightly cumbersome. A clunky but portable mutex is to try to create a directory, wait and try again if it already exists, remove it when you are done with the critical section.

But the simplest and obvious fix would be to move the `trap` out of the function.

```
#!/bin/bash

service_test ()
{
    while true; do
        # FIXME: don't hardcode escape sequences; use tput
        # FIXME: prefer printf over echo -n
        echo -n $'\e7\e[1;50H\e[0K'$(date  +%H:%M:%S:%N)$'\e8'
        sleep 1
    done
}

trap 'echo received SIGUSR1' SIGUSR1

service_test &
pid=$!

cat <<:
USE "kill '$$'" to kill the service
USE "kill -s SIGUSR1 '$$'" to send SIGUSR1 to the service
:
kill -s SIGUSR1 $$
wait $pid
```

Then, the `kill` should also be sent to the parent, so I updated to use `$$` instead of `$!`.

The background job terminates when the parent terminates. Thus, I added `wait $pid` to the end to keep the parent alive.

Comment: Perhaps notice also the absence of the `function` keyword. Bash supports it for backwards compatibility, but it was never a good idea; you should prefer the POSIX function declaration syntax. I fixed this in your question, too, whilst sorting out some other formatting issues.

Comment: what do you mean with set the trap outside of the function, i tried it, my service never get started ... and if i send kill -s SIGUSR1 to $! it gets terminated, instead of sending received signal. Background process are in complete subenvironments arent, they? it should be a trap for the background process and not for the active shell,
the goal is to send the background process a signal when it should read from a mkfifo pipe, because if i read inside the function from a pipe, the loop get stops until something is written to the pipe, pipe is blocking.

Comment: No background service are executed in a subshell - manual Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment, except that traps caught by the shell are reset to the values that the shell inherited from its parent at invocation. what does that mean from its parent at invocation? that means the process who open the shell which start the subshell, so the trap isnt set .....

Comment: I played around with this some more and have updated the answer. It might not do what you want (it's not very clear from the question; this is probably too minimal to be useful?) but it works and does what you ask.